# How to read Exported Excel file?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have exported entity records by `Export to Excel` , and saved it in local drive.What to do to make this data in tabular format.when I opened it in notepad,I show, its having data.I have only `OpenOffice 3.3` installed in my machine.I don't have MS Office Excel.But in `OpenOffice` its not showing anything.

FYI, I want to add new/update data, then import it to CRM. My target is to add new data and create a `CSV` file.

Please, suggest me a way.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to interact programmatically with the csv file?

Comment: OpenOffice 3.3 is ancient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files generated by `Export to Excel` functionality are in fact `XML` documents.

When you select `Static Worksheet with records from this page` without select `Make this data available for re-importing by including required column headings` you will get a file with `XLS` extension, but the file format is still `XML`.

When you select other options for export the data you will get a file with `XML` extension.

In both cases the file isn't compatible with `OpenOffice`, `LibreOffice` or other online editors (as far as I know), also if you upload the file to SkyDrive and try to open with `Excel Web App` will returns an error.

You need to use `Microsoft Excel` to view or modify these files.

Comment: I tried it with Google Drive, it works.

Comment: I tried also, I uploaded the XLS file but Google Drive throws "Sorry an error occurred", maybe you uploaded a file already opened and saved from Excel.

Comment: I actually uploaded an unrelated xlsx file and assumed that it would be the same ;> TIL that the exported file is an xml file with an xls extension (hence the error message: the file format and extension do not match)

Comment: so far for me Guido is right. LibreOffice,web readers,and google Drive didn't worked.

Comment: So your unexplored options are: Office 365, full Office, or Office Starter.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to buy Microsoft Office 2013 or Microsoft Office 365, but you could:

- Upload the xls file to Google Drive, make changes, and download as csv
- Install Microsoft Office Starter for free
- Install Libre Office 4 for free

The export is an xls file and is meant to be an export to Micosoft Office Excel.